# Need to modify a variable data to use as a "LIKE" in a COUNT query

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sql-like

I'm trying to use a numeric variable on a LIKE statement, but I do not know how to change the data to a numeric value.

Before we start, I apologize because I can't copy the table structure as I'm working with a "SQL environment" that does not allow me to see it, so I will do my best to explain it.

I have two tables:

- SAMPLE table

Code on the table :

```
SELECT sample_number,project,status,template,parent_aliquot,C_DUE_DATE_2
FROM SAMPLE
ORDER BY SAMPLE_NUMBER DESC
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaCs2.png)

- KPS_SMP_DUE_DATE_WEEK_PIVOT_VW

Code on the table:

```
select *
from KPS_SMP_DUE_DATE_WEEK_PIVOT_VW
where project = 'S/180308/01'
```

The important fields on this table are "PROJECT", "PRODUCT" and "YEAR". The fields seen on the right side of the table are not important.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRDJo.png)

I have this code :

```
SELECT vw.project,vw.year,(SELECT COUNT(s.sample_number)
                                      FROM SAMPLE s
                                      WHERE s.PROJECT = vw.PROJECT AND s.STATUS IN ('I', 'U', 'P') and s.TEMPLATE = 'KPS_DEFAULT' AND s.PARENT_ALIQUOT > 0 
                                      and s.C_DUE_DATE_2 < {ts '2021-01-20 00:00:00'} and s.C_DUE_DATE_2 LIKE '%'vw.year'%')
FROM KPS_SMP_DUE_DATE_WEEK_PIVOT_VW vw
where vw.project = 'S/180308/01' and vw.department = 'QC'
```

As seen before, "KPS_SMP_DUE_DATE_WEEK_PIVOT_VW" has entries categorized by the field "Year", so I'm trying to fetch the total amount of samples that have expired each year, by using this code:

```
SELECT COUNT(s.sample_number)
                                      FROM SAMPLE s
                                      WHERE s.PROJECT = vw.PROJECT AND s.STATUS IN ('I', 'U', 'P') and s.TEMPLATE = 'KPS_DEFAULT' AND s.PARENT_ALIQUOT > 0 
                                      and s.C_DUE_DATE_2 < {ts '2021-01-20 00:00:00'} and s.C_DUE_DATE_2 LIKE '%'vw.year'%'
```

I would like that the '%'vw.year'%' would work, and the expected result would be something like this :

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS3QP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `YEAR` or `DATEPART` function as follows:

```
YEAR(s.C_DUE_DATE_2) = vw.year
```

or

```
DATEPART(YEAR,s.C_DUE_DATE_2) = vw.year
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably extract the year value from C_DUE_DATE_2 and compare that value with vw.year

In your query, change

```
s.C_DUE_DATE_2 LIKE '%'vw.year'%'
```

with

```
YEAR(s.C_DUE_DATE_2) = vw.year
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have `C_DUE_DATE_2` indexed then it will be much faster to **NOT** use the `YEAR` function on it. Instead, construct a date interval covering that year:

```sql
s.C_DUE_DATE_2 >= DATEFROMPARTS(vw.year, 1, 1)
    AND s.C_DUE_DATE_2 < DATEFROMPARTS(vw.year + 1, 1, 1)
```